# Sylow $p$-subgroups of FSym($\mathbb N$)

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\FSym{FSym}$Let $\FSym(\mathbb{N})$ denote the finitary symmetric group on the set of natural numbers. How many Sylow $p$-subgroups does $\FSym(\mathbb{N})$ have for any prime $p$? Countably or uncountably many?

Comment: Follow-up: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398033/isomorphic-sylow-p-subgroups-of-fsym-mathbbn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncountably (continuum) many. A $p$-Sylow subgroup (or at least some of them) determines a nested partition (into $p$-element subsets, into $p^2$-element subsets, etc), and hence determines a partition into $p$-element subsets. There are continuum many such partitions and all are conjugate under the permutation group.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually wonder that are all Sylow $p$-subgroups of FSym($\mathbb{N}$) conjugate in FSym($\mathbb{N}$)? If so how?

Comment: This would make a separate question.

Comment: By 14.3.6 of Derek J. S. Robinson’s book [A course in the theory of groups] not all  Sylow p-subgroups are  conjugate, since FSym$(\mathbb{N})$ is a countable locally finite group. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to clarify that last comment, 14.3.6 in Robinson's book says that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of a countable locally finite group are all conjugate if and only if there are countably many of them.

Comment: Indeed, if the partitions into $p$-elements subsets don't coincide modulo a finite subset, then the possible $p$-Sylow are not conjugate in the finitary symmetric group. (They might still be conjugate under the whole symmetric group.)

Comment: It is known that the group constructed by J. Wiegold is a transitive Sylow $p$-subgroup of FSym$(\mathbb{N})$ [Prop 2.1, A.O. Asar, Permutation groups with cyclic-block property and $MNFC$-groups, Turk J. Math., 41 (2017),983-997].  It is worth to know the conjugates of W in FSym$(\mathbb{N})$ (even in the Sym$(\mathbb{N})$).

Comment: My comment may  generate a separate question, but I hope that  we stay in the same context:  Are all Sylows p-subgroups of FSym(\mathbb{N}) are isomorphic (maybe to $C_p\wr C_p\wr \dots$, the iterated wreath product of cyclic group $C_p$ of order $p$)?

Comment: @AhmetArikan they might be conjugate under the automorphism group. I'd suggest writing separately a question about a general description of Sylow subgroup in this group.